# Best way to get a single key from a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

Having a python dictionary and knowing it is made of just one key/value pair, what's the best way to retrieve that single/unique item?

So far I know I could use one of these two ways:

1. `list(mydict.keys())[0]` (same as `list(mydict)[0]`)
2. `next(iter(mydict.keys()))` (same as `next(iter(mydict))`)

As far as I understand, `list` performances are worse than `iter` ones so the latter approach should be better, right? Which ways is best? There's something that's even better than the two way I indicated? Please let me know.

Comment: There is no "first" when it comes to a dictionary, since its not ordered. Only keys are unique, and values can be duplicated without issue. Please describe the problem you are trying to solve here.

Comment: How do you want to process the key/value pairs?  Using a `for` loop is a common way to iterate (in Python3).  You can use `for key, value in mydict.items():`.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid In python3 dictionaries by default maintain insertion order. So technically, yes there is an order. If you add key/value for 'a' and then 'b' then 'c'. the .keys() operator should return them in that order.

Comment: @Erich: This is only true since Python3.6, and this behaviour "should not be relied upon" https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#new-dict-implementation

Comment: @BurhanKhalid : I removed the word "first" from my question replacing it with "single" to avoid misunderstanding

Comment: @FabienP : I think you are right ...and thank you for the reference link!

Comment: @cdarke : I'd avoid using a for loop if because I know I have only a single/unique item in my dictionary... as far as the for loop isn't the most efficient and convenient way even in this situation...

Answer (score 37, accepted):

> Which way is best?

I recommend using `next(iter(d))` over `list(mydict.keys())[0]` to retrieve a key from a dictionary. As you suspected, using `next(iter(d))` is *much* better in terms of efficiency.

The efficiency difference can be observed by timing each method:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> setup='from string import ascii_letters; d = {k: v for k, v in enumerate(ascii_letters)}'
>>> timeit.timeit(stmt='list(d.keys())[0]', setup=setup)
1.0895291733333334
>>> timeit.timeit(stmt='next(iter(d))', setup=setup)
0.2682935466666656
```

The choice of using `next(iter(d))` over `list(d.keys())[0]` becomes very, *very* obvious as the size of the dictionary increases:

```
>>> setup='d = {k: v for k, v in enumerate(range(500, 10000))}'
>>> timeit.timeit(stmt='list(d.keys())[0]', setup=setup)
98.52252842666667
>>> timeit.timeit(stmt='next(iter(d))', setup=setup)
0.2720192000000452
```

`next(iter(d))` performs so much better than `list(d.keys())[0]` mainly because it avoids creating a potential huge list of all of the dictionaries keys in memory, when it really only needs the first element.

Comment: Ok, thank you. So `next(iter(d))` is better than `list(d.keys())[0]`; is it the best way for the purpose also?

Comment: "Less instructions" is at most very weakly correlated with "more efficient". The time taken to execute an instruction varies wildly, especially for instructions like CALL_FUNCTION.

Comment: @user2357112 True. That is a good point. However, I also provided timings, and I believe that they provide a good idea of the efficiency of the two methods and help support my argument.

Comment: The timings are good, as is the part where you actually talk about the giant unnecessary list that `next(iter(d))` doesn't create, but the part about "uses less instructions, and thus is more efficient" is an invalid inference. I'd recommend just removing the disassembly and the conclusions drawn from it.

Comment: @user2357112 After doing more research, I see your point. I understand what you mean when you say the execution time of instructions can vary, especial for function calls. Thanks for explaining that. I now agree that's a weak argument. I'll remove it.

Comment: @ChristianDean is it possible to use `next(iter())` to obtain a single value also instead of `[*dict.values()][0]`

Answer (score 6):

Since the question assumes the dictionary has only one key-value pair, I'd like to add two more methods besides the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46042617/1166587).

- Use `dict.popitem()[0]`. `popitem()` returns the only key-value pair in tuple: (key, value). If you do not want to mutate the original dictionary, make a copy first.
- Build a set and then pop: `set(mydict).pop()`.

Simple performance comparisons in Python 3.9.6:

```
In [11]: import timeit

In [12]: timeit.timeit(stmt='d={1:2}; d.popitem()[0]')
Out[12]: 0.15144950605463237

In [13]: timeit.timeit(stmt='d={1:2}; next(iter(d))')
Out[13]: 0.1860927080269903

In [14]: timeit.timeit(stmt='d={1:2}; set(d).pop()')
Out[14]: 0.19704585697036237

In [15]: timeit.timeit(stmt='d={1:2}; list(d)[0]')
Out[15]: 0.2412048210389912
```

Comment: Thank you for your additional contribution on this

Comment: What if the dictionary is enormous? An update showing the timeit for a massive dictionary would be great.

Comment: How big? One dict key or value taking half of system memory?

Answer (score 3):

To get the "first" key-value pair from a dictionary, you will have to use an `OrderedDict`:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
d = OrderedDict()

#add items as normal

first_key = [a for a, b in d.items()][0]
print(d[first_key])
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about OrderedDict

Comment: Why not just: `next(iter(d))`, as in the other answers?